# How to retrieve the substring with in the string

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone.I have small doubt that is I have a path of my audiofile which is placed in the directory in resources folder that path is

```
/Users/Chary/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/B02404E5-52DC-49B6-8DBB-C9946E4331AF/BiblePlayer.app/raj/1.mp3
```

My question is how to retrieve the string "1.mp3" from that entire path?

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *fullPath = @"…";
NSString *fileName = [fullPath lastPathComponent];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *allString = @"/Users/Chary/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/B02404E5-52DC-49B6-8DBB-C9946E4331AF/BiblePlayer.app/raj/1.mp3"

int slashPosition = [allString rangeOfString:@"/" options:NSBackwardsSearch].location;
    NSString *function = [allString substringFromIndexslashPosition + 1];
```

This will get you the path of the file after the last slash

Answer (score 1):

try it:-

```
NSString *yourPath = @"/Users/Chary/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/B02404E5-52DC-49B6-8DBB-C9946E4331AF/BiblePlayer.app/raj/1.mp3";
NSString *fileName = [yourPath lastPathComponent];
```

It may help u thank :)

Comment: How is this different from my answer?